Is gender identical to sex?
There are two biological sexes, although some newborns may be intersex. Considerable research suggests that there may be several genders. Max Hirschfeld trailblazed this field since 1897 before being shut down by the Nazis in 1933. However, considerable confusion arises from assertions that males can become female or vice versa. Is this simply the result of the conflation of different properties, one biological and the other psychosocial?
I’m looking for references to the philosophical literature on this subject.

Can you clarify your definition for "gender," and what it would mean for there to be several?

See e.g. Feminist Perspectives on Sex and Gender.

Biology does not define two sexes. It explicitly notes that there are species with just one sex as an example, which would thus neither be male or female. And in theory there can be more, though I am not aware if biology has already found any species with more.  So science is not that dogmatic about sexes. Human biology recognizes 2 sexes by means of the chromosomes, which however can have various edge cases and may evolve to different genetic setups in the far future. The research from 100 years ago is outdated.

Relevant answer of mine

Perhaps gender is merely linguistic! Perhaps all it amounts to is the desire for certain pronouns to be used!

Gender is of course linguistic. The existence of linguistic genders allows people to consider gender identity separate from sex. Even English has had "they" for someone of indeterminate gender for centuries.

Gender with any meaning beyond grammar (e.g. le chat court partout comme un fou: sous la chaise belle, sur le canapé grand...) is a neologism adopted by some academics and activists in the late 60s meaning state of self-perception typically associated with the kind of sex that excludes boinking.
In the 80s, it eventually found its way into common use meaning kind of sex that excludes boinking, and eventually thereby onto myriad forms simply replacing sex (complete with two checkboxes, []Male and []Female), likely to save countless form-fillers from having to get told the same dad joke ten times a day. The only reason why this was useful at all is because sex meaning boinking was itself fairly new, having gradually expanded into common use over the first half of the 20th century.
For the past ten years or so academics and activists have been trying to push their usage into common use with moderate success.
So I guess that makes it a conflation of a conflation which was conflated with an element of a conflation in order to de-conflate that conflation.

The concept of gender distinct from sex predates the 1960s.

@Meanach I think an argument could be made for the 40s, but AFAIK it was the sort of word that had to be defined every time anybody used it, even in academic publications, until the 60s.

Of course grammatical gender distinct from sex predates the 1960s by hundreds of years at least, as does grammatical gender as a euphemism for sex, but I don't think those are what either of us meant.

I took your grammatical point, but my argument is not linguistic.  I would recommend looking at Hirschfeld's work on gender as a psychosocial concept in the early twentieth century. The idea of a third gender in certain cultures has a long history.

@meanach if you mean the idea, not the word, then I think definitely by the 40s as a cohesive idea in common academic use, probably earlier. This answer is about a word and its referents, not the history of an idea.

@Meanach as to trying to find gender as a concept earlier than the 20th century, I think this is an anachronistic framing that imports modern/western-globalist meaning that doesnt belong and obstructs superficially similar but significantly different historical/local meanings that do belong.

@g s I respectfully disagree.

I think the answer to your question is yes. If you travelled back to early human history, the differences between biological males and biological females were probably much starker than they are in modern society. With two such different beings, it makes some sense that when early societies began to shape the identity of youths, they would use a different set of rules to shape the identities of biological males vs biological females. Whether or not these rules make a ton of sense or whether or not they should be the only sets of rules is what is under the microscope in the modern age.
Judith Butler quote:
"Gender is not something that one is, it is something one does, an act… a ‘doing’ rather than a ‘being.’"

And the Gloria Steinem quote: "Few jobs really require a penis or vagina, so the rest should be open to everyone."

The nature and extent of sexual dimorphism in humans has not changed over the course of the historical era. What has changed is the invention and distribution of tools such as guns and vehicles that make the differences less significant.

@DavidGudeman good clarification, that is what I was intending to get at. I also meant within earlier societal frameworks the different (and of course perhaps unjustified) roles that each biological sex was required to participate in created a greater justification for the difference in identity conditioning that holds through today when the roles in society are supposed to be fundamentally equal.
